# How to send SOAP response?

Tags: perl, soap

We use an off the shelf application that is capable of sending SMS messages via SOAP calls but the user needs to provide the actual SMS sending service.

I've written the following simple Perl script (for testing) which works (i.e. an SMS message is successfully received) but the client always complains that the SMS didn't send.  I'm thinking this is because I'm not sending a SOAP response.

My question is how do I send a SOAP response?

Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;
use Data::Dumper;

use lib '/tmp/';

SOAP::Transport::HTTP::CGI
    -> dispatch_to('Vendor::Telephony')
    -> handle();

package Vendor::Telephony;

sub SMS {
    my $name = shift;
    my $data = shift;
    my $message = $data->{'SMSMessage'};
    my $number = $data->{'SMSNumber'};

    open(SMS, " | sendmail -r alerts\@example.com $number\@sms.provider.com 2> /dev/null");
    print SMS $message;
    close(SMS);
}
```

EDIT1:
I've modified my script based on your answer but I always get an error 500 in /var/log/httpd/access.log when I issue a 'return'.  The eror 500 is simply:

`172.23.34.18 - - [14/Apr/2019:09:24:16 +0800] "POST /cgi-bin/soap.cgi 
HTTP/1.1" 500 1806 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web 
Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000)"`

I used SOAP::WSDL's wsdl2perl to create the perl modules. The script now looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;
use lib '/tmp/lib';
use Data::Dumper;

SOAP::Transport::HTTP::CGI
  ->dispatch_to('Vendor::Telephony')
  ->handle;
BEGIN {
  package Vendor::Telephony;
  use vars qw(@ISA);
  use MyElements::SMSResponse;
  @ISA = qw(Exporter SOAP::Server::Parameters);
  use SOAP::Lite;
  sub SMS {
    my ($self, $body, $header) = @_;
    my $message = $body->{'SMSMessage'};
    my $number = $body->{'SMSNumber'};

    open(SMS, " | sendmail -r alerts\@example.com $number\@sms.provider.com 2> /dev/null");
    print SMS $message;
    close(SMS);
    return MyElements::SMSResponse->new({Status => 0});
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you've neglected to "use" your "MyElements::SMSResponse" package, and the return will fail for that reason, but you'd need to tell us what's being reported in the Apache error log to be sure.

Comment: Thank you again, have updated the code to reflect the script as of now.

Comment: You've made quite a few changes and things are getting messy. If it's still not working, you'll need to tell us what the error message is in /var/log/httpd/error.log

Comment: Sorry but literally nothing is being written to error.log, only the access.log.  I've noticed that if I remove he 'return' the http status changes from 500 to 200 but thw Windows client still complains.  I'll poke the vendor again and hopefully they'll start being helpful.  In the mean time, thank you for your help.

Comment: Errors and warnings should be logged *somewhere*. Do you have any way to generate debugging output from the program? You're not going to make this work flying blind.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Example section in the documentation for SOAP::Server at the following URL.

https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::Server

Note that the final statement in the handler returns SOAP::Data, except that there seems to be a slight error in the example: the method should be new(), not name().

Essentially, you need to construct your response as a SOAP::Data object and return() it. Hopefully you already know how the response is supposed to be structured, because I can't help you with that!

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've made 'EDIT 1' in response

Comment: Thanks still not there but you have been a huge help so I'm awarding the bounty.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to know more about the library to provide a 'good' answer, but, looking at:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl use SOAP::Transport::HTTP; 
   SOAP::Transport::HTTP::CGI   
    ->dispatch_to('C2FService')   
    ->handle; BEGIN {   package C2FService;   

use vars qw(@ISA);   
@ISA = qw(Exporter SOAP::Server::Parameters);  

use SOAP::Lite;   
sub c2f {
         my $self = shift;
         my $envelope = pop;
         my $temp = $envelope->dataof("//c2f/temperature");
         return SOAP::Data->name('convertedTemp' => (((9/5)*($temp->value)) + 32));   } }
```

Take a look at the `return`, which starts with `SOAP` and therefore provides (if I remember correctly a valid envelope. It's been a while since `SOAP::Lite` for me, but I do remember using https://www.soapui.org/ which helped the testing process a great deal.